# Array definition in class - in header or cpp file?

Tags: c++

I want to define array in class:

h:

```
class A
{
    protected:
        static const int TABLE[];
}
```

cpp:

```
const int A::TABLE[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

This should be a const array all object of type class A will use.

1. Should I define it in the header file? what is the best practice for this?
2. I sew previous questions and some suggested to define it with "extern". like this:

h:

```
class A
{
protected:
extern const int TABLE[];
}
```

cpp:

```
const int A::TABLE[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

it is insted of static?

............................

Comment: Either define it in exactly one source file or use `inline` in header inside class.

Comment: First of all, will the array be a separate member for each separate object instance of `A`, or should the array be shared by all object instances of `A`? That decides the use of `static` or not.

Comment: *"what is the best practice for this..."* Opinion based.

Comment: If you intend to change the values often, it is an advantage to only have to recompile the cpp file. However, if the values are useful at compile time, you need them in the header.

Comment: Unrelated, I'd also suggest `std::array<int, 5>` instead of `int[5]`

Comment: You cannot have an extern class member.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here. Either we can define it inside the class using the `inline` keyword with C++17 & onwards or declare it inside the class and then provide an out of class definition in **exactly** on source file.

##### Method 1

Here we use `inline` with C++17.

*header.h*

```
#pragma once 

class A
{
    protected:
//------vvvvvv---------------------------->inline used here with c++17
        inline static const int TABLE[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
};
```

[Demo method 1](https://onlinegdb.com/yzc1qKOYM)

---

##### Method 2

Here we declare it inside the class and then define it outside the class in exactly one source file.

*header*

```
#pragma once 

class A
{
    protected:
        static const int TABLE[5];
};
```

*source file*

```
#include "header.h"

const int A::TABLE[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

[Demo method 2](https://onlinegdb.com/4smP9lnwS)

---

Note that instead of using built in array I would recommend using `std::array`.